# .htaccess to deny all but one user agent

Tags: php, android, apache, .htaccess

I have created some php web pages for inserting webview & some json informations in an android app .

And I want to protect these directories via .htaccess to allow only one specified user-agent which come from the android app and all others should be denied.

I know that I can set a specific user agent to my webview by calling `mWebView.getSettings().setUserAgentString(value);` but how can I allow this user agent from .htaccess ? I tried a lot of methods but none works for me .

by the way Im hosting with Hostgator if this can help

Comment: https://serverfault.com/questions/253419/htaccess-config-to-block-depending-on-browser-agent ?

Comment: didn't work for me :/